# javascript в модальных окнах

Tags: javascript

Имеется модальное окно (упрощенно div.modal{position: absolute;})
Данное окно может подгружать различные страницы сайта, в том числе имеющие и js код.

Возникло несколкьо вопросов:

1. Как мне организовать для таких окон document.redy
2. как избежать redeclare function (если они написаны в тегах <script></script>)
3. Как мне выгружать js, который уже не нужен (по закрытию страницы)
4. Как мне обращаясь $(document) искать только к тому окну, которое открыл

Желательно все без eval.

Как решение у меня пока вертится одна мысль: сделать все через замыкания с описанием базовых прототипов для стандартных объектов. Например, весь код js со страницы помещается в функцию, где передаются параметры document, window. Вот только как быть с подгруженными скриптами?

```
(function (document, window){
    //some code from modal page
})(new MyDocument, new MyWindows);
```

В правильном ли направлении я мыслю?

Comment: 1. Ну ready же можно перехватывать в момент завершения XHR.
 2. Проверку на существование функций наверно лучше делать при объявлении.
 3. Что значит «выгружать»? Делать автоматом delete для всего?

Comment: 1. Клево! Посмотрю в эту сторону. Если поможете ссылкой на доку, будет здорово!
2. Хотелось бы абстрагироваться и не приписывать проверок к объявлению каждой функции
3. «Выгружать» - значит удалять их совсем из памяти (с замкнутыми функциями, думаю, это осуществимо - удаляются все указатели и сборщик мусора подчистит все, имхо)

Comment: А как ты собираешься подгружать в div.modal страницу?

Ну вот, к примеру, если jQuery('.modal').load – http://api.jquery.com/load/ – то у него есть перехватчик "complete", который можно ассоциировать с $(document).ready

Comment: Я бы сделал так. Написал бы простенький псевдо-window – простой объект, который заменял бы настоящий window, псевдо-document, который бы равнялся jQuery('.modal') . Эти объекты должны иметь необходимые для работы конкретные методы и атрибуты: close, location, etc...

Comment: Примерно такой подход я и описал в вопросе. Только вот как быть со скриптами, которые подгружаются по src? есть еще одна засада: <button onclick="someFunctionRun()">Go</button> - функция то глобально ищется, а тут она замкнута будет(

Answer (score 3):

В нужный момент (открытие модального окна) я бы вызвал $('.modal').load(), а в "complete" написал бы передачу этого кода в тот самый псевдо-document. Чтобы нормально отрабатывали inline-скрипты, все таки придется прибегнуть к eval. Нужно перебрать все элементы `<script>` в пришедшей разметке, и те, которые не имеют атрибута src – eval'ить. Только Eval'ить их надо в контексте псевдо-document'a (**UPD**: в контексте `window`). То есть, делать что-то вроде

```
$('script:not([src])').each(function(){
    if (!$(this).attr('src'))
    {
        $.globalEval(this.text || this.textContent || this.innerHTML || this.innerText || '');
        } else
        {
        $(document).append(this);
        }
    });
```

Тогда функции по-идее должны принадлежать главному window. А со встроенными скриптами с src все еще проще: просто добавляем их в DOM c помощью «живой» ф-ции `$.append()`. Недавно сталкивался с такой же проблемой, решил так же.

Comment: По поводу redeclare – никак. Я не нашел упоминаний о неких «обработчиках неопределенных методов JS» (есть такие в PHP например: `__call($name, $args)` – волшебный метод, который вызывается в случае вызова неопределенного метода). Так бы можно было бы перенаправлять их из `window` в `new_window`... Остается только успокоиться тем что в переопределении функций нет ничего плохого :)

А вообще, раз там такая ситуация, что это вызвало проблему, надо все нормально структурировать и разбивать на объекты :)

Comment: Идея почти совпадает с моей, но хочется все же сделать так, что как будто бы модальная страница - это отдельное окно-вкладка браузера. Плюсую.

Comment: Кстати, про ситуацию - это пока идея в голове)